# How to enable systemd on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, systemd, systemctl, amazon-linux

I started using Amazon Linux AMIs. It seems to have the **/etc/systemd/system/** folder, but I am not able to use **systemctl** to start stop a service I added to the **/etc/systemd/system/** folder.

```
$ systemctl
bash: systemctl: command not found
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Amazon Linux v 2.0 does support systemd and comes installed by default:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2.0 (2017.12)"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2.0"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2.0 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2.0"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

rpm -qa | grep -i systemd
systemd-libs-219-42.amzn2.4.x86_64
systemd-219-42.amzn2.4.x86_64
systemd-sysv-219-42.amzn2.4.x86_64`
```

Answer (score 9):

sadly that only amazon linux v2 support systemd. Amazon linux v1.0 does not
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/

Comment: Does amazon Linux v2 also support SYSVinit?

Answer (score 6):

Amazon Linux is ultimately based on an old version of CentOS/RHEL and doesn't support systemd.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=731256

Comment: That thread is funny. AFAIK the only people who "want" Amazon Linux are internal to Amazon. And maybe not even there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but now there's Amazon Linux 2, which will be awesome!!!1! I noticed that there have been very few updates to Amazon Linux 1 recently.

Answer (score 1):

So even though "Amazon Linux 2" should have this command by default, the docker image for it – `amazonlinux:2` – does not. To install it there use this directive:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN yum install -y /usr/bin/systemctl
```

Comment: This is not surprising. Docker images are not expected to contain systemd or any other init system, only your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a horrible hack to fill a gap in your scripts, a simple function *may* work for you. It only covers essentials and will break very easily.

With this you can perform **stop**, **start**, **restart**, **status** and **is-active** requests, such as `systemctl start docker`. Obviously the outputs won't match `systemctl`, although `is-active` provides the same text output on my system.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  function systemctl() {
    if [ "$1" == 'is-active' ]; then
      if [ -z "$(service $2 status | grep "is stopped")" ]; then
        echo "$2 is active"
      else
        echo "$2 is inactive"
      fi
    else
      service $2 $1
    fi
  }
```

You can extend it by putting the whole function definition into an if block to test for the OS type or existence of `systemctl` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use,
`sudo systemctl enable httpd` , just use `sudo chkconfig httpd on`

Here's the reference,
[AWSEC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

Comment: Amazon Linux 1 is obsolete, and so is that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Upon exploring, I found that `Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03` versions of Amazon Linux does not support `systemctl`.
But this does not mean that `init.d` services cannot be configured to autostart upon boot.

`chkconfig` can be used for implement the use case.

To configure my `init.d` service whose name was `ingester` :

```
sudo chkconfig ingester on
```

To list all the services:

```
sudo chkconfig --list
```

Here is [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) of `chkconfig` :

Comment: Amazon Linux 1 is obsolete.

Comment: I agree that it is obsolete, but when I had to configure my app  on a server which is using the obsolete version, I was not able to do it through systemctl. So I shared the answer with others.